# Javascript error in Chrome and Mozilla but not Opera. Name not defined

Tags: javascript, event-handling, onchange

So I have recently started programming pages... Little thins and I was trying something in a page that I had done previously so I just copied the code and changed the values. I was wondering if anyone can shade some light why it worked fine in my Opera browser but not on my Chrome or Firefox (I was using wamp for my computer act as a localwebserver)

What I did was using a  element and the change of it's value (the user selecting a date) to call a function that went to use ajax and call a database and return stuff, I don't think the details are needed)

So I had the following

```
<select name="daySelector" id="daySelectorId" onchange="changeDate(daySelector.value)">
    <option value="-1">Day</option>
    <option value="2012-01-30">2012-01-30</option>
    <option value="2012-01-31">2012-01-31</option>
    <option value="2012-02-01">2012-02-01</option>
    <option value="2012-02-02">2012-02-02</option>
    <option value="2012-02-03">2012-02-03</option>
    <option value="2012-02-04">2012-02-04</option>
    <option value="2012-02-05">2012-02-05</option>
    <option value="2012-02-06">2012-02-06</option>
    <option value="2012-02-07">2012-02-07</option>
    <option value="2012-02-08">2012-02-08</option>
    <option value="2012-02-09">2012-02-09</option>
    <option value="2012-02-10">2012-02-10</option>
    <option value="2012-02-11">2012-02-11</option>
    <option value="2012-02-12">2012-02-12</option>
    <option value="2012-02-13">2012-02-13</option>
</select>
```

Opera worked just fine and returned what I wanted...
But Chrome and Firefox for some reason say that daySelector is not defined... When I use the 'this' reference all browsers work just fine. The funny thing is that the project I took the code from was something I did before I update my pc which had only firefox installed (an older version that is) and I am pretty sure it didn't cause any problems...

So any ideas. I realize this is not a problem per se but I am curious about details like this and I wanted to know... BTW, to those that have programmed in html/ajax/js/... for more than a few months... Should I just pass the whole element and take what I need inside the function?

Comment: I would use `this`. I've never seen that sort of referencing before.

Answer (score 2):

Opera is likely referencing `document.daySelector.value` whereas FF and Chrome are referencing `window.daySelector.value`. Replace with `this.value` it will be bound to the node.

Comment: Sounds about right. On Chrome (stable), I can reference an element by simply typing its name into Console.

Comment: Ohhh, okay that actually does help... I was just reading something similar just a while ago about the same thing only in netscape... Thanks... And sorry for taking your time with not really a problem but curiosity...

Comment: That's what the site is for, no need to apologize :)

Answer (score 1):

Replace your onchange with: `onchange="changeDate(this.value)"`

daySelector isn't defined in that context. Opera must handle it for you or silently be consuming the error.

Comment: "daySelector isn't defined in that context" what do you mean with that. Is it because of the nature of html pages, how they are static and every time they load they are new and what not. How are they defined then. (I think the other project I mentioned was in php files, could it make any difference)

Comment: The OP said that he used `this` and it worked, but so did `daySelector` in the same context (on an older browser). He's asking why.

Comment: @AndreasAndreou See AlienWebguy's response.  Clearly he reads better than I do as I missed that you noticed `this` works.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
onchange="changeDate(daySelector.value)"
```

with

```
onchange="changeDate(this.value)"
```

this should work fine

Answer (score 0):

The submitted answers are correct, however I would urge you to look at jQuery as this would be a lot simpler and it is cross browser.

For example:

```
// Select the form element by id using the jQuery selector
var daySelector = $('#daySelectorId');

// Set the onchange event
daySelector.onChange(function(){
     // Get the value of the form element
     var value = $(this).val();
     // Call the change date function
     changeDate(value);
});
```

I appreciate that this may seem a little complex, but if you break it down it will make sense, that is why I have put in clear comments.

Once you have 'got the jist' of jQuery, you will be able to compress the above statement into:

```
$('#daySelectorId').onChange(function(){changeDate($(this).val())});
```

Just place this into your javascript code and remove the 'onchange=changeDate(day...' attribute from your html.

**You will not need to worry about this not working cross browser**

Make sure you look at the jQuery documentation to learn how to implement it. Again, it is very easy. Quick example using Google Code (dont forget to get an API key from Google, link found below):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=GENERATED_API_KEY"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("jquery", "1.7.1");
</script>
```

The above will simply load jQuery into your website. Place this into all of your webpages that you would like to use it.

Get your API key here: http://code.google.com/apis/loader/signup.html

Hope this helps

Comment: That's a heck of a lot of code to include simply to grab a `select` value. JQueryUI wouldn't help at all here and it's like 200k.

Comment: I didn't mean to include the jQueryUI, hence, I removed it. True, it is a few more lines of code, however, it is good practice to use jQuery as it is fast becoming the basis of most javascript based applications. In cases like this then there is a fair argument to go with just plain javascript, but in most cases it is better to use jQuery. In addition, it allows you to do much more with ease.So maybe not for this scenario but for future scenarios, @Andreas may be better off using jQuery.